# Mystery shadow image is HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to learn how floating toolbars work.  I cannot determine where the shadow to the right and bottom of the floating left Facebook/Twitter share bar is coming from on the following page:

http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/608931

It doesn't appear to be in the CSS and I can't find any Javascript that applies it.  It also doesn't appear to be part of the background image it sits on top of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The floating tool bar is a `ul#share_side_bar`

and in the CSS (global.css):

```
.topics #share_side_bar {
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #333333;
}
```

using firebug if you toggle that rule off the shadow disappears

Comment: So if I wasn't using Mozilla/Webkit the shadow wouldn't appear?  Is there a way to achieve this effect in IE?

Comment: yes it browser dependant on support. IE has a couple of filters, Dropshadow and Shadow, last I looked it wasn't nearly as pretty using them, but I'll check

Comment: also the site could be using a script to IE to play nice.. edit.. no there's no shadow for that site in IE.. maybe they decided the filters weren't worth it ;)

Comment: You're Welcome.. if it's any help I just found [this demo](http://hedgerwow.appspot.com/demo/shadow) showing how to implement something similar in IE8 and below (apparently IE9 supports box shadow ;))

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the global.css stylesheet you'll find:

```
.topics #share_side_bar {
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #333333;
}
```